# Correct MVVM pattern WPF Command implementation

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm, command

I'm trying to implement commands following the MVVM pattern, but I'm stuck with this particular scenario.

In the XAML I've binded a command to a button inside a column:

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Delete" Header="" UnboundType="Object" Width="20" FixedWidth="True">
    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        <dxe:ButtonEditSettings AllowDefaultButton="False">
            <dxe:ButtonEditSettings.Buttons>
                <dxe:ButtonInfo GlyphKind="Cancel" Command="{Binding DeleteRowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=testView}"  />
            </dxe:ButtonEditSettings.Buttons>
        </dxe:ButtonEditSettings>
    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

In my ViewModel I've declared a DelegateCommand:

```
Private m_deleteRowCommand As DelegateCommand(Of Object)
Public Property DeleteRowCommand() As DelegateCommand(Of Object)
    Get
        Return m_deleteRowCommand
    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As DelegateCommand(Of Object))
        m_deleteRowCommand = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I initialized the command inside the ViewModel's constructor:

```
DeleteRowCommand = New DelegateCommand(Of Object)(AddressOf DeleteRowCommandExecute)
```

And finally I execute the command:

```
Private Sub DeleteRowCommandExecute(ByVal parameter As Object)
    Dim sender As TableView = parameter
    Dim row = sender.DataControl.CurrentItem
    Dim index = sender.FocusedRowHandle
    sender.DeleteRow(index)
End Sub
```

Everything works as expected, but as far as I know the ViewModel should know nothing about the View, therefore deleting the row inside the ViewModel is incorrect.

What is the best way to do this following MVVM pattern?

**UPDATE:**
Deleting the item from the ObservableCollection binded to the ItemsSource of the Grid works perfectly, but what if I need to remove an UI element like a StackPanel from a Grid which don't have an ItemsSource?

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Delete" Height="25" Width="100" Command="{Binding DeleteItemCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**UPDATE2:**
My goal is to have a container to which I can add items (UserControl) dynamically and where I'm able to change the order of this items at runtime.
At the moment I'm using a Grid as a container to which I add a new RowDefinition everytime I insert a new item.
I the use Grid.Row property to keep track and change the items' order.
This way I need to do all the delete operations in the code behind since I have to manually remove the RowDefinition from the Grid.

Comment: How do you set the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`? If you are using e.g. an `ObservableCollection` you can remove the entry from your ```and your view will get updated automatically.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom The ItemsSource is indeed an ObservableCollection and after making some adjustments I was able to make it work just by deleting the corresponding item from the collection. But what if I need to delete an ui element, let's say a StackPanel, from a Grid which doesn't have an ItemsSource property?

Comment: Well done, so you don't need any more help?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom I updated the question.

Comment: Why are you using a `StackPanel` inside a `Grid` with one column and one row just to place a `Button`? `Grid` and `Stackpanel` are not visible and for positioning. I guess your approach is not the best when you have to change their visibilty. If you really have to you could work with `IValueConverter` for example.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom That was just an example to show that the approach you suggested for the GridControl would not have worked in that situation because of the Grid not having an ItemsSource.

Answer (score 0):

> Deleting the item from the ObservableCollection binded to the ItemsSource of the Grid works perfectly, but what if I need to remove an UI element like a StackPanel from a Grid which don't have an ItemsSource?

Since this code is purely *view-related*, it should be implemented in the code-behind of the view (or in the control itself where it applies). The view model shouldn't know anything about any UI elements so it makes no sense to implement a command that removes these elements.

MVVM is not about eliminating *view*-related code from the views. It is about separation of concerns. So keep everything that is related to `UIElements` and `Panels` in your view.

Comment: Actually when I click on the button inside the StackPanel I need to remove the StackPanel from the Grid and also remove an item from an ObservableCollection inside the ViewModel.

Comment: Then you should use an ItemsControl that you bind to a source collection and then add the StackPanel to the ItemTemplate.

Comment: I updated my question. You then suggest to use an ItemsControl instead of the Grid? In that case, in order to change the order of the items should I add a custom index property to my UserControl?

Comment: Just bind the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl to an ObservableCollection<YourDataObject> and then add, remove or move items in the ObservableCollection from the view model class.